# pyspark- how to calculate percentage

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with product id, name, and weight. I hope to calculate the percentage of products that weighted between 10-20, and also 50-60. I can think of a naive way which is count all the rows, and count the rows have weight 10-20, also 50-60, and do a division. What would be a better way to do this? Can we use some built in functions? Many thanks for your help.

```
id. name. weight
 1.   a.    11
 2.   b     15
 3.   c     26
 4.   d.    51
 5.   e.    70
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `F.avg` to get the percentage of whether the column `weight` is between a given interval. `.cast('int')` returns 1 if the comparison is true, else 0. Its average will be the percentage you wanted to calculate.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select(
    F.avg(F.col('weight').between(10,20).cast('int')).alias('10_20'), 
    F.avg(F.col('weight').between(50,60).cast('int')).alias('50_60')
)

df2.show()
+-----+-----+
|10_20|50_60|
+-----+-----+
|  0.4|  0.2|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: thanks! where can I find the doc for this? for example i did not know the `between`

Comment: See [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.between)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want conditional aggregation:

```
select avg(case when weight between 10 and 20 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_10_20,
       avg(case when weight between 50 and 60 then 1.0 else 0 end) as ratio_50_60
from t;
```